# При установке monodevelop падает ошибка

Tags: linux, unity3d, monodevelop

```
    ~ $ sudo apt-get -f install mono-complete
Чтение списков пакетов… Готово
Построение дерева зависимостей       
Чтение информации о состоянии… Готово
Некоторые пакеты невозможно установить. Возможно, вы просите невозможного,
или же используете нестабильную версию дистрибутива, где запрошенные вами
пакеты ещё не созданы или были удалены из Incoming.
Следующая информация, возможно, поможет вам:

Пакеты, имеющие неудовлетворённые зависимости:
 mono-complete : Зависит: mono-runtime (= 5.8.0.108-0xamarin1+debian9b1) но он не будет установлен
                 Зависит: mono-runtime-sgen (= 5.8.0.108-0xamarin1+debian9b1) но он не будет установлен
                 Зависит: mono-utils (= 5.8.0.108-0xamarin1+debian9b1) но он не будет установлен
                 Зависит: mono-devel (= 5.8.0.108-0xamarin1+debian9b1) но он не будет установлен
                 Зависит: mono-mcs (= 5.8.0.108-0xamarin1+debian9b1) но он не будет установлен
                 Зависит: mono-roslyn (= 5.8.0.108-0xamarin1+debian9b1) но он не будет установлен
                 Зависит: mono-csharp-shell (= 5.8.0.108-0xamarin1+debian9b1) но он не будет установлен
                 Зависит: mono-4.0-gac (= 5.8.0.108-0xamarin1+debian9b1) но он не будет установлен
                 Зависит: mono-4.0-service (= 5.8.0.108-0xamarin1+debian9b1) но он не будет установлен
                 Зависит: monodoc-base (= 5.8.0.108-0xamarin1+debian9b1) но он не будет установлен
                 Зависит: monodoc-manual (= 5.8.0.108-0xamarin1+debian9b1) но он не будет установлен
                 Зависит: libmono-cil-dev (= 5.8.0.108-0xamarin1+debian9b1) но он не будет установлен
                 Зависит: referenceassemblies-pcl но он не будет установлен
                 Зависит: msbuild но он не будет установлен
                 Зависит: ca-certificates-mono (= 5.8.0.108-0xamarin1+debian9b1) но он не будет установлен
E: Невозможно исправить ошибки, у вас отложены (held) битые пакеты.
```

установил unity3D а mono не запускается. При установке падает целая простынь ошибок. Пробовал aptitude -f, apt-get -f, устанавливать все зависимости по очереди, удалить и ничего не помогает. понятно что проблема с зависимостями. может у кого то есть варианты, а то не хочется переустановливать систему а моно нужен капец как сильно.

Comment: а в `aptitude`'е зависимости полуавтоматически разрулить не получается? И какая система, действительно ли нужен моно-5+ и откуда он взялся?

Answer (score 1):

Проблема исправлена. Извините за беспокойство. Необходимо было подключить репозиторий с пакетами.

Comment: Какой репозиторий? Сделай ответ более развёрнутым, чтобы потом гуглящие смогли у себя исправить проблему.

Comment: http://www.mono-project.com/download/stable/

Comment: просто после команды apt-get update как описано по ссылке, у меня почему то репозиторий терялся. у меня сработало без update

Comment: Алекс, помоги, пожалуйста. Что именно ТЫ прописал и где???????????????????????

Comment: @Митяй675 Ну насколько я помню, я просто не вбил **sudo apt update**. Почему то после обновления пакетов удалялся репозиторий и при установке не подтягивались необходимые зависимости. У тебя какая ОС?